# FileNotFoundException when using FileInputStream

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I am trying to access a file I have contained in the jar.

The beginning of my code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class intro {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    URL jarUrl = intro.class.getResource("myFile.jar");
    File myJar = new File(jarUrl.toString());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myjar);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\...myFile.jar (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at intro.main(intro.java:10)
```

It seems to have no problem finding the URL or initializing the file, but I can't get the FileInputStream to work.  Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access Jar'ed resources in this manner.  A file in a Jar is not a `File` (ie as in a file system file), they are different concepts.

You should use the `URL.openStream` instead.

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = jarURL.openStream();
    // ... Read from stream
} catch (IOException exp) {
} finally {
    try {
      if (is != null) {
        is.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }    
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (that's the other reason the close statement is in a try-catch ;))

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no probs, your correction is more correct, I'm just lazy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect on an number of levels:

1. This is wrong, because a URL is not a file name:

   ```
   File myJar = new File(jarUrl.toString());
   ```

   Assuming that `jarUrl` has type `java.net.URL`, it should be written as:

   ```
   File myJar = new File(new URI(jarUrl));
   ```
2. This is wrong because it would (assuming that `myJar` was correct) open the JAR file as byte stream:

   ```
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myJar);
   ```

   In fact, you need to open it using the JAR / ZIP file classes, and then use them to open a stream on the file contained by the JAR.  It should be something like this:

   ```
   ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(myJar);
   ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry(filePathInZip);
   InputStream is = entry.getInputStream();
   ```

   (I've left out all of the necessary exception handling and code to close things to prevent resource leaks.)
3. This looks wrong as a URL:

   ```
   file:\...myFile.jar
   ```

   What is with the backslash and the three dots?  A well-formed URL would not use `\`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a known resource, you can just use:

```
InputStream is =intro.class.getResourceAsStream("myFile.jar");
```

The other answers are making some assumptions when they say you're doing this wrong. But it is suspicious that you are trying to get to a Jar first as a resource, and then as a file...

Also, see this: [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 0):

I won't beat around the bush, and I will straight away go to the point. You can't access the file inside the jar in this way. Instead try the below code.

```
URL jarUrl = intro.class.getResource("myFile.jar");
InputStream is = null;
String s = new String();

try {
       is = jarURL.openStream();
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);

       while(scan.hasNextLine){    
          s = scan.nextLine() + s;    
       }       
 } catch (IOException exp) {
 } finally {        
     is.close();
 }
```